# Query to compare two columns from two different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I have a Column in one Index with a number of Countries in it, I want to check whether these countries are similar or same as countries in the Column in another index.

So it is like, in one index we have user data with the countries user has specified and in the other index we have the master data with the actual countries. So now I want to check whether the countries entered by the user are the same as the ones in master data.

If anybody knows how to write a query for this in Kibana, kindly help.

```
GET final,master/_count

{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"script": {"script":"['A_OPERATINGCOUNTRY'].value == ['AD_Country Name.keyword'].value"}}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage this outside Elasticsearch. But, since the incoming data doesn't have the country name you want, why do you want to check this on Elasticsearch? The form you are using should have the exactly value you want to index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Suppose we have an index of page access logs like so:

```
PUT /mybeat-2018/_doc/1
{
    "host" : "elastic.co",
    "ttl" : 40
}

PUT /mybeat-2018/_doc/2
{
    "host" : "elastic.co",
    "ttl" : 666
}

PUT /mybeat-2018/_doc/3
{
    "host" : "google.com",
    "ttl" : 55
}
```

and an independent whitelist that can shrink or grow, with a bunch of hosts:

```
PUT /whitelist/_doc/1
{
 "hosts" : [
   {
     "name" : "elastic.co"
   },
   {
     "name" : "twitter.com"
   }
 ]
}
```

Then a search on the `mybeat-*` for whatever is in the whitelist should reference the whitelist document (in our case the document with id: 1) like so:

```
GET /mybeat-*/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "host" : {
                "index" : "whitelist",
                "type" : "_doc",
                "id" : "1",
                "path" : "hosts.name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```